# Error instalación Rcpp en R-Studio

Tags: r, rstudio, packages

Estoy intentando instalar el paquete Rcpp en R desde R-Studio pero me aparece el siguiente error. Estoy trabajando con versión 4.0.2 de R y versión 1.3.1056 de R-Studio. Agradezcosus inmensamente su cordial colaboración. Feliz día.

```
[1/8] Installing Rcpp...

Warning in utils::install.packages("Rcpp", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/") :
  'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.2/library"' is not writable
Error in utils::install.packages("Rcpp", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/") : 
  unable to install packages
Calls: sourceWithProgress -> eval -> eval -> <Anonymous>
Ejecuci n interrumpida
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto: __C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.2/library"' is not writable__ es el quid de la cuestión, tal vez no lo estás instalando con los permisos de administración?

Comment: Hola, nos podrías compartir el código que utilizaste  para instalar las librarías, o que método utilizaste.

Comment: Coincido, si estás en usando un computadora en un entorno administrado (universidad, oficina, etc) lo más probable es que no tengas permiso para escribir en esa carpeta. Me pasó varias veces con Rcpp. Alternativa: rstudio.cloud si estás trabajando con pocos datos (las instancias tienen poca RAM), hablar con quién administra esas compus para que instale la librería como admin o te de permisos para hacerlo.

Comment: Respecto a sus preguntas y sugerencias les respondo:

1. Esto: C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.2/library"' is not writable es el quid de la cuestión, tal vez no lo estás instalando con los permisos de administración?.....¿Cómo puedo revisar eso? Saludos.


2. Hola, nos podrías compartir el código que utilizaste para instalar las librarías, o que método utilizaste..... Opción Install en el módulo de ayuda y visualización y también con la función install.packages().
3.

Comment: 3. 
Coincido, si estás en usando un computadora en un entorno administrado (universidad, oficina, etc) lo más probable es que no tengas permiso para escribir en esa carpeta. Me pasó varias veces con Rcpp. Alternativa: rstudio.cloud si estás trabajando con pocos datos (las instancias tienen poca RAM), hablar con quién administra esas compus para que instale la librería como admin o te de permisos para hacerlo...... Es mi computadora personal estimado. Agradezco tu sugerencia.

Comment: Miguel, tal vez estas en un entorno corporativo y no eres administrador de tu propio equipo, en cuyo caso hay que pedir la instalación a la gente de IT. Sino, si tienes una cuenta con la que administras tu equipo, ingresa con esta.

Comment: Patricio, muchas gracias por su respuesta. Voy a ver qué soluciono porque es muy extraño ya que estoy trabajando en computador propio y según lo que me comentan, eso es un poco extraño. Muchas gracias.